# How to install Cindy Component on Delphi XE5?

Tags: windows, delphi, installation, components, delphi-xe5

I install [cindy component](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcycomponents/) in delphi xe5 and it gives this error when installing dpkCindyDBXDXE5.bpl:

```
Can't load package C:\Component\cyComponents6\DbExpress\dpkCindyDBXDXE5.bpl.
%1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

How to solve ?

Comment: Download the source, open the .dpk file, build and install that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that you are trying to load the 64 bit version of the package. This should not be loaded at design time. The instructions for building the Cindy library include building both the 32 bit packages and 64 bit packages. Make sure that you build both but only the 32 bit package (pkCindyDBXDXE5.bpl) should be in the same folder as the dpkCindyDBXDXE5.bpl file.